# Customizing mat-select in angular-material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this mat-select that should be look like this:

[image]

so what i need is to customize the mat-select to have this arrow head. pls help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::ng-deep` to override styles for a css class.
Find out with dev tools which classes are used in the material select component and override them with your needs. Also it is best practise to use `:host` in combination with `::ng-deep` to avoid those styles to have effect to any parent components.

See https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Example:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
   .class-name-here {
       background-color: grey;
   }
}
```